StackOverflowError null springboot
I want to build a page that makes a request to the backend to get some data, but i have a problem fetching those results. I will attach the error and all the code that is involved:
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525) ~[na:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.prependPath(JsonMappingException.java:455) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:790) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]

JS function:
function getAppointments(button) {
        const day = button.getAttribute('data-day');
        const month = button.getAttribute('data-month');
        const year = button.getAttribute('data-year');

        fetch(`/getAppointments?day=${day}&currentMonth=${month}&currentYear=${year}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {

                // Afiseaza rezultatul in div-ul 'appointments'
                const appointmentsDiv = document.getElementById('appointments');
                appointmentsDiv.innerHTML = ''; // Sterge continutul anterior

                // Construiește div-uri pentru fiecare programare
                data.forEach(appointment => {

                    const appointmentDiv = document.createElement('div');
                    appointmentDiv.classList.add('appointment');

                    // Adaugă numele și prenumele, bolduite
                    const nameDiv = document.createElement('div');
                    nameDiv.innerHTML = `<strong>${appointment.patientProfile.lastName}, ${appointment.patientProfile.firstName}</strong>`;
                    appointmentDiv.appendChild(nameDiv);

                    // Adaugă data și ora
                    const dateTimeDiv = document.createElement('div');
                    dateTimeDiv.textContent = `Date & Time: ${appointment.appointmentDate}, ${appointment.appointmentHour}`;
                    appointmentDiv.appendChild(dateTimeDiv);

                    // Adaugă detalii
                    const detailsDiv = document.createElement('div');
                    detailsDiv.textContent = `Details: ${appointment.details}`;
                    appointmentDiv.appendChild(detailsDiv);

                    // Verifică valoarea lui fulfilled și adaugă butonul corespunzător
                    const fulfilledDiv = document.createElement('div');
                    fulfilledDiv.classList.add('fulfilled');
                    if (appointment.fulfilled) {
                        fulfilledDiv.textContent = "Fulfilled";
                    } else {
                        const button = document.createElement('button');
                        button.textContent = "Fulfill";
                        button.addEventListener('click', () => markAsFulfilled(appointment.id));
                        fulfilledDiv.appendChild(button);

                        const prescriptionButton = document.createElement('button');
                        prescriptionButton.textContent = "Create Prescription";
                        prescriptionButton.addEventListener('click', () => redirectToPrescriptionCreation(appointment.id));
                        appointmentDiv.appendChild(prescriptionButton);
                    }
                    appointmentDiv.appendChild(fulfilledDiv);

                    // Adaugă div-ul cu programarea în div-ul principal
                    appointmentsDiv.appendChild(appointmentDiv);
                });
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('Error fetching appointments:', error));
    }

backend code:
@GetMapping("/getAppointments")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Appointment> getAppointments(@RequestParam int day, @RequestParam int currentMonth, @RequestParam int currentYear){
        return calendarService.getAppointments(day, currentMonth, currentYear);
    }


@Override
    public List<Appointment> getAppointments(int day, int currentMonth, int currentYear) {
        DoctorProfile doctorProfile = doctorProfileRepository.findByUserId(userService.getAuthenticationUser().getId());
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(currentYear, currentMonth, day);
        return appointmentRepository.findAllByDoctorProfileIdAndAppointmentDate(doctorProfile.getId(), localDate);
    }

The getAppointments function retur if alright, so it is not a problem coming from database. I have to mention that i have overrided the hashCode function.
@Table
@Entity
@Data
public class Appointment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
    private boolean fulfilled;

    @Column(name = "appointment_date")
    private LocalDate appointmentDate;

    @Column(name = "appointment_hour")
    private LocalTime appointmentHour;

    private String details;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name ="doctor_id")
    private DoctorProfile doctorProfile;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="patient_id")
    private PatientProfile patientProfile;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "appointment", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Prescription prescription;

    public Appointment(DoctorProfile doctorProfile, PatientProfile patientProfile){
        this.doctorProfile = doctorProfile;
        this.patientProfile = patientProfile;
    }

    public Appointment(){}

    // Pentru clasa Appointment
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        result = prime * result + (fulfilled ? 1231 : 1237);
        result = prime * result + ((appointmentDate == null) ? 0 : appointmentDate.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((appointmentHour == null) ? 0 : appointmentHour.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((details == null) ? 0 : details.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((doctorProfile == null || doctorProfile.getId() == 0) ? 0 : doctorProfile.getId());
        result = prime * result + ((patientProfile == null || patientProfile.getId() == 0) ? 0 : patientProfile.getId());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Appointment{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", fulfilled=" + fulfilled +
                ", appointmentDate=" + appointmentDate +
                ", appointmentHour=" + appointmentHour +
                ", details='" + details + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}```



----------------------


JavaScript is not Java. Your question seems to be unrelated to JavaScript.

@jabaa ofci know java is not js, but i have an error fetching those objects, this is why i put the js code as well.

You should first try to isolate the problem. Can you reproduce it without JavaScript, e.g. with curl or Postman? If yes, it's unrelated to JavaScript.
